# interpretation of combinatorial term of partition function

Tags: combinatorics, quantum-field-theory

I'm currently reading A. Zee "Quantum Field Theory in Nutshell". There is a problem called baby problem which is to evaluate following partition function.
$$ Z(\lambda ,J) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq \exp\left(-{\frac{1}{2}m^2q^2+Jq-\frac{\lambda}{4!}q^4}\right)$$
first expanding by $\lambda$ and then differentiating repeatedly by $J$ one gets following expression.
$$Z(\lambda ,J) = \Bigl(\frac{2\pi}{m^2} \Bigr)^\frac12 \exp\left[{-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\Bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial{J}} \Bigr)^4} \right]\exp\left(\frac{1}{2m^2}J^2\right)$$
after getting this we are interested in term of given $\lambda$ and $J$.

For example if we want to check the term with power of $\lambda=1$ and power of $J=4$ one gets,
$$Z(\lambda=1 ,J=4) = \frac{8!(-\lambda{J^4})}{{4!}^3(2m^2)^4}$$
where I mean $Z(\lambda=1,J=4)$ as term with 1th power of $\lambda$ and 4th power of $J$.
after that there are bunch of "baby Feynman diagrams" associated with each given $\lambda$ and $J$.

**I want to understand relation of these diagrams and combinatoric term** (e.g. $8!/(4!)^3$).

First thing I tried was, to evaluate general term for given $\lambda=n,J=2k$, and got result,
$$Z(\lambda=n ,J=2k) = (-1)^n\frac{(4n+2k)!}{(4!)^n(2n+k)!(2k)!}\frac{\lambda^nJ^{2k}}{(2m^2)^{2n+k}}$$
here combinatorial term is $\dfrac{(4n+2k)!}{(4!)^n(2n+k)!(2k)!}$.

What I understood is, to get this fraction one needs,

- $n$ identical elements each constructed by $4$ identical elements, giving $(4!)^n$
- $2n+k$ identical elements giving $(2n+k)!$ term.
- $2k$ identical elements giving $(2k)!$ term.

but I don't understand the term $(4n+2k)!$ term, which one may think as permutation of $4n+2k$ identical elements, but what is this element associated with? (e.g. by looking at above general expression $2n+k$ term can be associated to $2m^{2}$)

Also, what kind of combination this fraction all together represents?
Also, how can one interpret this fraction by "Feynman diagram"?

Sorry for somewhat ambiguous question. Hope this makes sense.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try a [canonical integral from DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/36.2) to find Z?